# EGui with glfw in rust

Tags: rust, glfw, egui

Currently learning openGL in rust and decided to add e-gui, to make immediate changes.
Decided to use this crate: https://crates.io/crates/egui_glfw_gl/0.13.1

After adding it to `Cargo.toml` can't build or run.

```
PS opengl_t_2> cargo run
   Compiling glfw-sys v3.3.5
error: failed to run custom build command for `glfw-sys v3.3.5`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `opengl_t_2\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-d98b92fc73a7f019\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = Some("C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\")
  running: "C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\" "C:\\Users\\Vasily\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\glfw-sys-3.3.5\\." "-G" "Visual Studio 16 2019" "-Thost=x64" "-Ax64" "-DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF" "-DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF" "-DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=opengl_t_2\\target\\debug\\build\\glfw-sys-52652cf8f267b532\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_DEBUG= -nologo -MD -Brepro" 
"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  failed to execute command: program path has no file name
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
cgmath = "0.16.1"
gl = "0.10.0"
image = "0.19.0"
tobj = "0.1.6"
num = "0.2.0"
rand = "0.5.5"
egui = "0.17.0"
egui_glfw_gl = "0.13.1"

[dependencies.glfw]
git = "https://github.com/bjz/glfw-rs.git"
default-features = false
```

Without egui-glfw, everything builds and I have a functional 3d scene.

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJWKH.png)

I apologize, if this is a stupid question, but I have already tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CMAKE = Some("C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\")
> ```

For whatever reason, your `CMAKE` environmental variable is pointing to a directory rather than the `cmake.exe` binary.

Make sure that you have cmake installed, and edit your `CMAKE` envvar to point to it. Or remove it, if cmake is in your `PATH`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should either have a CMAKE variable pointing to the .exe or having the path to the .exe in the PATH variable? Because calling 'cmake' from the terminal works.